# C# Winforms Web Browser

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a simple program which allows me to input a location and generate a google maps link which I can view on the Web Browser module wihtin visual studio. See code below:

```
string InvoiceQueryLocation = BackgroundLabel1.Text + BackgroundLabel2.Text;
MapBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/maps/search/" + InvoiceQueryLocation + "/");
MapBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

However, until about a week ago, everything worked fine until the default web browser (Chrome I think) decided it needs updating within the "webbrowser" module. Now, the maps query runs, stops for a second and then the Chrome update tab appears over it.

I have tried setting "AllowNavigation" to False, however, this stops me from clearning the results and starting anew.

Does anyone know a solution around this? Or perhaps know what I have missed?
I have tried this on multiple PC's and the same issue occurs each time.

Fixes I have tried -

- Updating windows
- Updating Vis studio
- Updating chrome
- Setting "AllowNavigation" to False

Comment: Not exactly clear (to me) what problem you're referring to, but you're still using the old (deprecated) WebBrowser Control. You should move to [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and ended up replacing web browser control with Microsoft's new WebView2 control

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms

I have a sample application based on the above link here....

[Sample Application - Use address or lat long to find address](https://github.com/vinaybhide/WebView2_ReverseGeoCode)